# What is the best buffer management drop policy?

Tags: performance, networking, queue, buffer, benchmarking

I am working on project that contains a *fixed-size buffer* of type (**FIFO**): First input First Output, where clients send their requests to that buffer, and the system handles them.When the buffer is full, I have to apply one of the following overloading policies (Drop Policies):
 **DRPH** : Drop one Request from the Head of buffer. 
**DRPT**: Drop one Request from Tail of buffer.
**DRPR**: Drop 25% of elements in the buffer randomly. 
**BLCK**: block new connections until space is available in buffer.

I made a simulation to measure the performance using  [Httperf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httperf) by sending many requests per second and measuring the response time, but I have got unstable values for response time especially when the requests number is large. so by simulation  I can not get the best drop policy. I repeated the simulation many times, each time I have got different values.

**The question is :**
theoretically, what is the best *buffer management drop policy* among the mentioned policies? .

Comment: Define 'best'. Maybe the real solution is not to have a fixed sized buffer. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP : I mean : what is the policy that will get best performance. it is restricted to use a fixed-size buffer.

Comment: It depends entirely on what the clients do when they don't get a response, for example whether they retry, how often, with/without back off, how many times, etc. If there are no retries the best performance would be achieved by always dropping all of them.  Surely it's the *purpose of your project* to evaluate these policies? And why those specific four choices? Still not a real question.

Comment: @EJP : thanks for your replay. frankly, the project for university, We implement everything, and we measure time . but we cannot figure out what is the best policy, we googled it, we find nothing about comparison between these policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely depends on your data and in which order it is needed. But usually, with a FIFO, the data at the end of the buffer is the oldest and so the one with the least likelhood to be required again. So DRPR is probably the best solution. But only if you can afford losing data (e.g. because it can be re-inserted later). If that is not the case you have to block connections until buffer space is available again.

Another thing: I would strive for a dynamic buffer. Start with a reasonable default size and see how quick it fills up. Above a certain rate increase the buffer size (and below a certain threshold you can lower it again) up to a certain maximum.

Comment: thanks, this is a useful answer, right now , but not the exact desired answer.